# git add . error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a Ruby on Rails repo to github, and just today it is giving me the following error:

```
******-*********:myapp *************$ git add .
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb
fatal: adding files failed
```

This has just started occurring (things were working fine yesterday).  What could have changed and how do I solve this?  Thank you.

Comment: It has nothing in common with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Review the permissions on `.git` directory.

To change all perms, you could execute the following:

```
sudo chown -R your-username:staff .git
```

Then you should be able to add files.

Comment: This is what shows up for .git:

drwxr-xr-x  13 **********  staff   442 Nov 14 14:52 .git